# Getting error during authentication in IOS using WSO2

Tags: ios, swift, wso2, identityserver4

I am new for WSO2 and using for the authentication in iOS app but i am getting authentication error after providing profile and username permission.

Getting **"Something went wrong during the authentication process, Please try signing again"**

WSO2 server is setup remotely and SSL certification also configured.

Step 1 [image]
Step 2 [image]

In iOS app I am using AppAuth SDK for authentication. Demo code is working fine with other identity server(Gluu  and identity) but getting error with WSO2 identity server.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logs?

Comment: @Sajith no error logs print and not getting any error event. My demo code is working fine with other identity servers.